# Setting Screen to Format on all Windows PC sizes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The game looks fine inside the Unity screen view, but if I build and choose a different resolution screen size the game looks goofy and dis-proportioned. Especially when I go into full screen mode. I'm using Unity 2019.1.1a (I think it's still in beta?). I'm developing a top down 2D game for Windows PC.

How can I fix it to where the game will look the same on any screen size?

Comment: you need to be more specific. to answer this question a whole chapter of unity docs won't suffice. if you are talking about new unity UI, you need to show what have you set for the camera or the UI

Comment: I can add an image. I basically created low resolution walls and a floor. Walls are different color than the floor. Level one is white floor and black walls. I designed 1 door rooms, two door rooms, three door rooms and four door rooms. Each room type has its own camera and a collider that cuts on that camera as well as deactivates the last rooms camera. The rooms are empty because it's a simple maze game. Anyway, I made the rooms prefabs and I drag and drop them into the scene. But when I use different resolution than my game screen, it looks bad. I'll add a pic shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity has some good tutorials on this topic:

https://unity3d.com/es/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui/ui-tools-resolution-device-independence

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html

Comment: Thank you! I will look through this and let you know if I find the answer that I seek.

Comment: I clicked your top link and within 12 minutes he told me exactly what I needed to know! I always wondered what the anchors actually were used for! And this taught me how to design my own ratio aspects! I've been wanting to design on mobile platforms and the video even shows how to switch platforms! I've always had problems with JDK/SK setup, so not sure if I'll be able to utilize this, but here's to hoping! Muchas gracias, amigo!